# Docker swarm constraint wildcards

Tags: docker, constraints, wildcard, docker-swarm

I am running a Docker swarm across 10 different host/servers/machines all labeled differently e.g.
nginx_1
nginx_2
nginx_3
nginx_4
app_1
app_2
app_3
app_4
testing_1
testing_2

Using Docker swarm constraints is there a way to specify which node a service can run on using a label and wildcard which would tel the service to run on any node with a label starting with nginx e.g.

```
--constraint 'node.labels.name ==nginx*'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't use wildcards in `--constraint` for the time being.

You could [label all your nginx nodes with a new label](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/manage-nodes/#add-or-remove-label-metadata), for instance:

```
docker node update --label-add type=web node1
docker node update --label-add type=web node2
...
```

And [use `--constraint` to create your nginx service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints---constraint) on `web` labeled nodes only:

```
docker service create \
--name nginx \
--constraint 'node.labels.type == web' \
nginx
```

Comment: That's what i ended up doing thought wanted to see if there was a way to do it using wildcards